# Sometimes the timer prints itself inside of the boundaries at random times(snake game)

Tags: c

I'm building a snake game in which there are 3 levels of difficulty. This function displays the timer for each level and it starts with 0 to infinity. There are times when the timer suddenly starts to increase itself by 10. For example the timer hits 1:10 and then for like 10 seconds increases itself by 10 instead of 1(1:20->1:30->1:40->1:50 etc ...)

Also Sometimes the timer prints itself inside of the boundaries at random times in the snake game. For example the timer hits 1:31 and it randomly prints that inside of the walls. It happens occasionally and very randomly. Is there a way to fix this problem because i can't find it.

void startscr()
{

```
    system("mode con cols=100 lines=40");
start:

    over = 0;
    system("cls");
    printf("   ******   **    *       *      *    *  ******           ******      *        **    **    ******   \n");
    printf("   *        * *   *      * *     *   *   *                *          * *      *  *  *  *   *        \n");
    printf("   ******   *  *  *     *****    ****    ******           *  ***    *****     *  *  *  *   ******   \n");
    printf("        *   *   * *    *     *   *   *   *                *    *   *     *   *    **    *  *        \n");
    printf("   ******   *    **   *       *  *    *  ******           ******  *       *  *    **    *  ******   \n");
    printf("\npress s to start game\n");
    printf("press r to see ranking\n");
    printf("press x to exit\n:");
    char input = _getch();
    if (input == 's') {
    select:
        system("cls");
        printf("   ******   **    *       *      *    *  ******           ******      *        **    **    ******   \n");
        printf("   *        * *   *      * *     *   *   *                *          * *      *  *  *  *   *        \n");
        printf("   ******   *  *  *     *****    ****    ******           *  ***    *****     *  *  *  *   ******   \n");
        printf("        *   *   * *    *     *   *   *   *                *    *   *     *   *    **    *  *        \n");
        printf("   ******   *    **   *       *  *    *  ******           ******  *       *  *    **    *  ******   \n");
        printf("\nselect the level\n\nhigh->press h\n\nmiddle->press m\n\nlow->press l\n");
        char lev = _getch();
        if (lev == 'h') {
            difficulty = 3;
            system("cls");
            cursor(0);
            make_stage_high();
            HANDLE thread1 = (uintptr_t*)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, (_beginthreadex_proc_type)stopwatch, NULL, 0, NULL);
            Sleep(100);
            HANDLE thread2 = (uintptr_t*)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, (_beginthreadex_proc_type)snake_move_high, NULL, 0, NULL);
            WaitForSingleObject(thread2, INFINITE);
        }
        if (lev == 'm') {
            difficulty = 2;
            system("cls");
            cursor(0);
            make_stage_mid();
            HANDLE thread1 = (uintptr_t*)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, (_beginthreadex_proc_type)stopwatch, NULL, 0, NULL);
            Sleep(100);
            HANDLE thread2 = (uintptr_t*)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, (_beginthreadex_proc_type)snake_move_mid, NULL, 0, NULL);
            WaitForSingleObject(thread2, INFINITE);
        }
        if (lev == 'l') {
            difficulty = 1;
            system("cls");
            cursor(0);
            make_stage_low();
            HANDLE thread1 = (uintptr_t*)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, (_beginthreadex_proc_type)stopwatch, NULL, 0, NULL);
            Sleep(100);
            HANDLE thread2 = (uintptr_t*)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, (_beginthreadex_proc_type)snake_move_low, NULL, 0, NULL);
            WaitForSingleObject(thread2, INFINITE);
        }
        if (lev == ESC) {
            goto start;
        }
        else {
            printf("wrong selection\n");
            printf("press enter to continue...");
            while (getchar() != '\n');
            goto select;
        }
    }
    else if (input == 'r') {
        if (rank_call() == 0)goto start;
        printf("press enter to continue...");
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        goto start;
    }
    else if (input == 'x') exit(0);
    else {
        printf("wrong input\n");
        printf("press enter to continue...");
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        goto start;
    }
}
```

This is the time function:

```
void stopwatch() {
    clock_t s, n;
    s = clock();
    while (over != 1) {
        n = clock();
        cursor(0);
        gotoxy(14, 0);
        printf(" %d : %d", ((n - s) / 1000) / 60, ((n - s) / 1000) % 60);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    nowrec.minute = ((n - s) / 1000) / 60;
    nowrec.sec = ((n - s) / 1000) % 60;
    return;
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown any of the game code that might potentially write outside of array boundaries, use unintialised variables, etc.

Comment: Where is the code with timer?

Comment: Updated and added the time function.